# Bootsrap 5 - change color mode dropdown from svg to i-icons

Tags: javascript, html

The sample for the color mode selector is overloaded with the svg definitions.
So i tryed to change the code to use Icons via i Tag.
Changing html worked well. Switching Mode is also working well.
My drawback is, that the Icon in den dropdown selector is not changing.
Maybe i have something wrong in the JavaScript?
I can't find a solution in the discussions or forums.
Can some one help me out?

I changed the html and javascript code.
I have used i tag icons and switching themes is working well.
If i change the theam, the icon in the selection dropdown is not changing.
Maybe i have something wrong in the Javascript?
Can someone help me out?

```js
/*!
 * Color mode toggler for Bootstrap's docs (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2023 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.
 */

(() => {
  'use strict'

  const getStoredTheme = () => localStorage.getItem('theme')
  const setStoredTheme = theme => localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)

  const getPreferredTheme = () => {
    const storedTheme = getStoredTheme()
    if (storedTheme) {
      return storedTheme
    }

    return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'
  }

  const setTheme = theme => {
    if (theme === 'auto' && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'dark')
    } else {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', theme)
    }
  }

  setTheme(getPreferredTheme())

  const showActiveTheme = (theme, focus = false) => {
    const themeSwitcher = document.querySelector('#bd-theme')

    if (!themeSwitcher) {
      return
    }

    const themeSwitcherText = document.querySelector('#bd-theme-text')
    const activeThemeIcon = document.querySelector('.theme-icon-active use')
    const btnToActive = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-theme-value="${theme}"]`)
    const svgOfActiveBtn = btnToActive.querySelector('i use').getAttribute('href')

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]').forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('active')
      element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false')
    })

    btnToActive.classList.add('active')
    btnToActive.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true')
    activeThemeIcon.setAttribute('href', svgOfActiveBtn)
    const themeSwitcherLabel = `${themeSwitcherText.textContent} (${btnToActive.dataset.bsThemeValue})`
    themeSwitcher.setAttribute('aria-label', themeSwitcherLabel)

    if (focus) {
      themeSwitcher.focus()
    }
  }

  window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', () => {
    const storedTheme = getStoredTheme()
    if (storedTheme !== 'light' && storedTheme !== 'dark') {
      setTheme(getPreferredTheme())
    }
  })

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showActiveTheme(getPreferredTheme())

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-theme-value]')
      .forEach(toggle => {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const theme = toggle.getAttribute('data-bs-theme-value')
          setStoredTheme(theme)
          setTheme(theme)
          showActiveTheme(theme, true)
        })
      })
  })
})()
```

```html
      <div class="dropdown ms-auto link-light bd-mode-toggle">
          <button class="btn btn-link nav-link dropdown-toggle d-flex align-items-center"
              id="bd-theme"
              type="button"
              aria-expanded="false"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-label="Toggle theme (auto)">
            <i class="bi bi-circle-half my-1 theme-icon-active"><use href="#circle-half"></use></i>
            <span class="visually-hidden" id="bd-theme-text">Toggle theme</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end shadow" aria-labelledby="bd-theme-text">
            <li>
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-theme-value="light" aria-pressed="false">
                <i class="bi bi-sun-fill me-2 opacity-50 theme-icon" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#sun-fill"></use></i>
                Light
                <i class="bi bi-check2 ms-auto d-none" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#check2"></use></i>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-theme-value="dark" aria-pressed="false">
                <i class="bi bi-moon-stars-fill me-2 opacity-50 theme-icon" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#moon-stars-fill"></use></i>
                Dark
                <i class="bi bi-check2 ms-auto d-none" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#check2"></use></i>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button type="button" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center active" data-bs-theme-value="auto" aria-pressed="true">
                <i class="bi bi-circle-half me-2 opacity-50 theme-icon" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#circle-half"></use></i>
                Auto
                <i class="bi bi-check2 ms-auto d-none" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#check2"></use></i>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```